# MySQL: how to select the record with the most recent update date

Tags: mysql

How do I select the records with the most recent update dates?  Sample data:

```
id, update_date, data_point
1, 2013-03-01, AAA
1, 2013-03-02, AAB
1, 2013-03-03, AAC
2, 2013-04-02, BAS
2, 2013-04-05, SOR
3, 2013-01-01, AAW
3, 2013-02-02, AJS
```

What query can I write to select rows 3, 5, and 7- the latest record for each id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to join the table on itself, using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.update_date, t.data_point
FROM yourtable t
   JOIN (
       SELECT id, MAX(update_date) max_update_date
       FROM Yourtable 
       GROUP BY id
   ) t2 on t.id = t2.id AND t.update_date = t2.max_update_date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f901b/1)

---

Returned Results:

```
ID   UPDATE_DATE          DATA_POINT
-------------------------------------
1    March, 03 2013       AAC
2    April, 05 2013       SOR
3    February, 02 2013    AJS
```

Comment: Thanks!  And in case there is a tie with max_update_date, is there an easy way to break the tie?

Comment: @user2517677 -- np, glad I could help.  In regards to ties, depends on which result you want.  If an arbitrary value is fine, selecting the `MAX(data_point)` would probably suffice.